# Connection timed out for AWS ubuntu cloud instance after ufw disable and enable

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2, connection, timeout

I configured AWS EC2 ubuntu 12.04 instance and configured it as a web server. I successfully tested the webserver from my local maching using the Elastic IP.

While trying to install cpanel, there was a step which asked to disabled the firewall(CentOS in the tutorial), I searched the web and used the following command to disable it on Ubuntu

**$ sudo ufw disable**

Before a server restart, I re-enabled the firewall with eh command

**$ sudo ufw enable**

This command did showed me that it will change the behavior for the SSH connections. I agreed and pressed Y.

I restarted the server and when I tried to connect to the instance with the following command

**$ sudo ssh -i key.pem ubuntu@XX.XXX.XXX.XX**

It gave me this error

**ssh: connect to host xx.xxx.xxx.xx port 22: Connection timed out**

I tried to search the amazon FAQ page, but there was no ticket on this. 
Can anyone help me resolve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Today I ran into the exactly same situation. Here's how I fixed it in 3 easy steps :

**Warning : Make sure your volumes are EBS, otherwise you will loose data in it.**

Suppose **INSTANCE-BROKEN** is screwed up.

> **1.) PREPARE :**

Create a new EC2 instance **INSTANCE-FIXER**.

***IMPORTANT :** This EC2 instance should be created in the same region (It was "us-west-1b" in my case) that has INSTANCE-BROKEN*

**Stop INSTANCE-BROKEN**.
Detach the volume from INSTANCE-BROKEN and attach the volume to INSTANCE-FIXER

> **2.) FIX :**

Now start INSTANCE-FIXER and run **fdisk** to see what available volumes you have there :

```
    sudo fdisk -l

    Disk /dev/xvda1: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes
    255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1044 cylinders, total 16777216 sectors
    Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disk identifier: 0x00000000

    Disk /dev/xvda1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

    Disk /dev/xvdf: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes
    255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1044 cylinders, total 16777216 sectors
    Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disk identifier: 0x00000000

    Disk /dev/xvdf doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Mount the volume and edit this file as shown :

```
    sudo mount /dev/xvdf /mnt
    sudo vi /mnt/etc/ufw/ufw.conf
```

Edit and make sure **ENABLED=no** in the file.

unmount the device "/dev/xvdf" from INSTANCE-FIXER

detach the volume from INSTANCE-FIXER

> **3.) DONE :**

Attach at "**/dev/sda1**"  --- **IMPORTANT - ROOT device, otherwise your instance won't start*

to the INSTANCE-BROKEN

Start the INSTANCE-BROKEN, now it should work; and

**Terminate** the INSTANCE-FIXER.

Now you can Login with SSH.

Comment: Very nice answer, helped me! Just one issue we faced - if you attach the broken volume to the new machine BEFORE starting it, then the machine doesn't start. You have to first start the new machine and then attach + mount the broken volume.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me as well. Luckily, I was working on 2 terminal windows, and I didn't get booted off one of the sessions. What I did is I allowed incoming traffic on the default ssh port(22). This worked for me:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

i did something similar:

i had to opened 8080 port in order to run tomcat, after that i can't loggin in via ssh.  i have test many things, like remove the port opened, but nothing seems to help.  always get timeout error.

i also open Echo Request and i get ping back response, so ..is there, but no for ssh.

if somebody could help us, it would be great.